# Search element in indexed array

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie with MongoDb I have a document with this structure :

```
{
    "_id": "570a38612959856808fe9b1d",
    "author": "foo",
    "books": {
        "570a385737000012009e6f65": {
            "title": "a1",
            "status": "published"
        },
        "570a385737000012009e6f66": {
            "title": "a2",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        "570a385737000012009e6f67": {
            "title": "a1",
            "status": "published"
        }
    }
}
```

how can I search for all authors that have pending books ?
I tried something like

```
{ "books":{$elemMatch:{"status": "pending" }}}
```

but got nothing

Comment: With such schema where you have hash keys it would be pretty difficult to query unless you can change it so that the dynamic book ids are embedded in an array.

Comment: You actually want a structure like `"books": [{ "_id": "570a385737000012009e6f65", "title": "a1", "status": "published" },{..}]` Which then makes for simple queties like `{ "books.status": "pending" }`. Point is that named keys need an "explicit" path, but without them the name of the "path" is the same for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that this is not the ideal structure for your data, but it is possible to query for all authors who have pending books using the `$where` operator. The `$where` operator takes a Javascript function:

```
db.authors.find({"$where" : function() {
    if (this.books) {
        for (var i in this.books) {
            if (this.books[i].status == 'pending') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}});
```

...or a Javascript expression (essentially the contents of the function as a string):

```
db.authors.find({"$where" : "if (this.books) { for (var i in this.books) { if (this.books[i].status == 'pending') { return true; }}} return false;"});
```

You can still specify which fields to return, etc.

```
db.authors.find({"$where" : function() {
    ...
}},{author:1});
```

More information on the `$where` operator:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/